Gradle from 4 to 6 - transitive dependency behaviour change
I have project where I have to upgrade to Gradle 6 from 4.
In 4 the compile contained the transitive dependencies but in 6 it seems to behave differently. I tried to use api for this dependency but no luck unfortunately.
the output of ./gradlew dependencies in 4:
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation' instead).
+--- com.XXX:system-integration-common:1.0.0.147
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12 -> 1.7.19
|    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.12 -> 1.7.19
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.19

the same in 6:
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- com.XXX:system-integration-common:1.0.0.147
+--- com.XXX:xxx-common:4.0.0.145

As I understand as of Gradle 5 the compile and runtime dependencies are separated (in 4 the compile dependencies contained all the transitive dependencies). However I don't think the solution would be to specify all these transitive dependencies as direct dependencies?
At the moment the relevant dependency looks like
dependencies {

    api "com.XXX:system-integration-common:1.0.0.147"

Probably I misunderstand something, could you please help what I am missing? Thank you!
